# Apache - Changing domain name and restricting access

Tags: apache-2.2

I have two websites already configured (not by me) on Apache server (under Debian):

- `beta.mydomain.com` that is located in `/www/sitebeta`
- `mydomain.com` that is located in `/www/site`

I've also created a new "landing page" located in `/www/sitelanding`

What I want to achieve is to configure the server so:

1. the `mydomain.com` would point to `/www/sitebeta` if it is accessed from a predefined range of IP addressess
2. If domain `mydomain.com` is accessed from anywhere else, it should point to `/www/sitelanding`

How can I achieve that? I suppose I would have to edit apache.conf, but is there any DNS configuration needed as well? (since the domain already points to that server). How can I restrict to these IPs - via .htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

No DNS configuration is needed - you can do this using mod_rewrite and using RewriteCond to match certain %{REMOTE_ADDR} values and then do a RewriteRule to the sitebeta folder.

I think it would look like something like the following in a .htaccess in the /www/site folder (I didn't test this, but I think it's correct or at least will point you in the direction).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^123\.123\.123\.123$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^234\.234\.234\.234$
RewriteRule (.*) /www/sitebeta/$1 [L]
```

Comment: So in fact I can make it happen just using proper `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Yes. I added an example to get you started.

Comment: @Gacek did this solve your situation?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the chance to test it yet, as soon as I will I will inform you and accept/comment your answer.